# Equivalent in C of the fortran format '(3g20.7)'

Tags: c, formatting, fortran, printf

I am not very familiar with the FORTRAN text formatting and I wonder what would be the exact equivalent in C of:

```
// Here 1 is the unit number and x, y, z are 3 double values
write(1,'(3g20.7)')x,y,z
```

using `printf` ?

(I am translating a program and I need the result to be exactly the same)

Comment: Do you have some sample output?

Comment: From [FORMAT SPECIFICATION](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-13.html): **13.5.9.2.3 G Editing.** The `Gw.d` and `Gw.dEe` edit descriptors indicate that the external field occupies *w* positions, the fractional part of which consists of *d* digits, unless a scale factor greater than one is in effect, and the exponent part consists of *e* digits.

Comment: Also consider [this link](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlf101l.doc/xlflr/formatdirected.htm#formatdirected). Basically, `G` can sometimes act like `F` and sometimes act like `E` depending on the values of the input and the specified widths. This is similar to the `%g` or `%G` specifier in C, but you will have to check all the boundary conditions. So, start with `"%20.7g%20.7g%20.7g\n"`, and tweak the format as necessary if it doesn't quite match the FORTRAN output.